# setting s3 bucket policy while PutObject

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
public String getPolicy() throws Exception {
        String policy_document = "{\"expiration\": \"2020-01-01T00:00:00Z\",\n" +
                "  \"conditions\": [ \n" +
                "    {\"bucket\": \"bucket\"}, \n" +
                "    [\"starts-with\", \"$Content-Type\", \"image/\"],\n" +
                "    [\"content-length-range\", 0, 100]\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";
        String aws_secret_key = "xxxxx";
        String policy = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(policy_document.getBytes("UTF-8"))
                .replaceAll("\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "");

        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        hmac.init(new SecretKeySpec(
                aws_secret_key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1"));
        String signature = (new BASE64Encoder()).encode(
                hmac.doFinal(policy.getBytes("UTF-8")))
                .replaceAll("\n", "");

        return policy;
    }
```

While uploading -

```
   ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
   objectMetadata.setHeader("policy", getPolicy());

   s3Client.putObject(bucket, key, inputStream, objectMetadata);
```

Can we pass policy header like above to reject s3 putObject requests that violate policy conditions ?

I think it is possible via `s3Client.setBucketPolicy` but is there a way to set these policies for each put request ?

Comment: Intuition suggests this may be an [XY](http://xyproblem.info) question... because I'm unable to understand why would you want to use a header to impose a constraint on an upload you are doing, or what it seems like that would accomplish.  The reason form posts have a policy is because the browser is uploading the object.  `s3Client.putObject()` isn't the browser -- it's your code.

Comment: Yeah you are right about this. Using a lib on top if s3 lib which has not implemented the setObjectPolicy at bucket level and so the lookout for other implemention